# Search apps list using keyboard

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, keyboard, external-keyboard

When looking through the list of installed applications I am able to search for an app by name quickly using PC keyboard on Genymotion emulator or when I plug in an USB keyboard to my Galaxy S2 through USB-on-the-go.

But I want to do the search on Galaxy S2 using soft keyboard. How to do this? I am pretty sure that I could do this with soft keyboard because the software "Wi-Fi keyboard" is able to do this. The question is only how to make a soft keyboard appear on the screen.

I have latest official firmware (Android 4.1.2, rooted) available for it.

Comment: If your device has the corresponding buttons, long-pressing the menu button should bring up the soft keyboard. Works on my devices, but I'm not sure if that's a general rule.

Comment: @Izzy: no, it doesn't call the soft keyboard.

Comment: Sorry to read that. It should be able to call up the keyboard via an intent, so you could use some automation app capable of invoking intents (such as Tasker) and define a suiting trigger (e.g. shaking the devices 2 times up/down). That's pretty much all I can think of – unless there's a tool integrating with the notification area, or allow you to [customize soft buttons](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546) (mostly requiring root for that).